# Comparing Data In Text Boxes in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

So I mostly use Microsoft Excel for a lot of my work and the most "Programming" I do is writing basic logical functions in excel.

I am setting up a windows form in Visual Studio 2013 and I want to the end user to be able to be able to confirm that the data they input into TEXTBOX1 matches what is in TEXTBOX2.

So normally in excel I can just write =IF(C2=D2,"Yes","No")

So basically I want to be able to input data in the carton field and then in the label field and if it matches I want it to say yes in the text box at the bottom.

I tried writing

```
    If CartonBarcode = LabelBarcode Then
        PartCheck = "Yes"
    Else : PartCheck = "No"
    End If
```

but that hasn't worked - I am very new to VB so please be gentle.

Eventually I also want to be able to append the scanned data (If the two text boxes match) into an excel spreadsheet.

[image: Blank Form]

[image: Correct Part]

[image: Incorrect Part]

[image: IF Statement In Excel]

Thanks in advance for all your help =)

---

Thanks for your help Mark - that makes a lot of sense.

I added this IF Statement to the PartCheck text box but it doesn't seem to display Yes or No regardless of what I put in.

It now throws two errors (look to be the same error on each line.)

Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Any further help you can provide would be fantastic

Screenshot of errors

[image: String Cannot Be Converted To Text]

I then changed PartCheck = "Yes" to PartCheck.Text = "Yes" and it runs but then nothing displays in the PartCheck Text Box

[image: PartCheck.Text]

[image: Part Check Text Box is still blank]

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, `TextBox` and other GUI components (e.g. `Label`, `Button`) are objects, with properties and methods to interact with them.  If you want to compare the text that has been entered into two `TextBox` objects, you will need to compare their [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties. e.g.

**Update**

Updated code below based on your updated question.  You are correct that you need `PartCheck.Text = "Yes"` to set it correctly.  Your current issue is *when* you are performing the check.  You are handling the `TextChanged` event for your `PartCheck` `TextBox`, but your logic should really be triggered when either the `CartonBarcode` or `LabelBarcode` text is changed.  You can either have `TextChanged` handlers for both of those `TextBox` controls, and call a common subroutine to perform the check, or have a common `TextChanged` handler, as shown below:

```vb
Private Sub Barcode_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles CartonBarcode.TextChanged, LabelBarcode.TextChanged
    If CartonBarcode.Text = LabelBarcode.Text Then
        PartCheck.Text = "Yes"
    Else
        PartCheck.Text = "No"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - Still need a bit more help as i'm still getting a blank text box when the text box should be display yes or no.

Comment: @AJW1985 Updated the answer based on the addition info in the question.